# Return the name of the MySQL column where a select match was

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM profiles 
 WHERE phone = :query 
    OR email = :query 
    OR facebook = :query 
    OR instagram = :query
```

I need to know what columns the match occurred in. So if the match occurred in.

How do I get that data in the MySQL query?

Edit: The optimal result would be to get all names of matched columns in the returned row.

Edit 2: If I have this table:

```
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| ID |  Name   |     email      |     phone      | facebook | instagram |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
|  0 | Jill    | jill@aol.com   | (123)123-1245  | fbjill   | igjill    |
|  1 | Jack    | jack@aol.com   | (123)111-1111  | fbjack   | igjack    |
|  2 | Bob     | bob@aol.com    | (123)222-2222  | fbbob    | igbob     |
|  3 | jMarie  | jill@aol.com   | (123)123-1245  | none     | none      |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

and I query this:

```
SELECT *
      FROM profiles 
     WHERE phone = fbjill 
        OR email = fbjill 
        OR facebook = fbjill
        OR instagram = fbjill
```

I need it to return the all the data of the row but with an additional columns stating the name of the columns it came from.

Comment: What happens if more than one column happens to match?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would like it to return a the name of all columns matched.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry it's in PDO

Comment: @Strawberry fixed. thanks, I trimmed down my code for the question.

Comment: Edit your question to provide the desired result for a representative data set. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CONCAT_WS` here:

```sql
SELECT *,
    CONCAT_WS(',', IF(phone = :query, 'phone', NULL),
                   IF(email = :query, 'email', NULL),
                   IF(facebook = :query, 'facebook', NULL),
                   IF(instagram = :query, 'instagram', NULL)) AS matching_cols
FROM profiles
WHERE -- your conditions here
```

This would return a CSV string, consisting of up to 4 columns, which matched the incoming `:query` string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can SELECT your conditions.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    phone = :query as phone_match,
    email = :query as email_match,,
    facebook = :query as facebook_match,
    instagram = :query as instagram_match
FROM profiles 
WHERE 
    phone = :query 
    OR email = :query 
    OR facebook = :query 
    OR instagram = :query
```

That will return 1 for each match, 0 for non-matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
SELECT *,
       MAKE_SET (       (phone = :query) 
                  + 2 * (email = :query) 
                  + 4 * (facebook = :query) 
                  + 8 * (instagram = :query), 'phone', 
                                              'email', 
                                              'facebook', 
                                              'instagram') from_where
FROM profiles 
HAVING from_where != ''
```

or the same with LIKE operator (see <kbd>[**fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40d06592045223ab1822c565d20089df)</kbd>).